# SQL Server Connection issues

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server instances installed on my Windows 7 :

- First one : `SQLEXPRESS` - no specific database
- The other one : `MSSQLSERVER` (classical) - several development databases...

Let's say my computer's name is `SERVERNAME`

- Using connection string `SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS` is ok.
- Using connection string `.` is ok and connects to `MSSQLSERVER` instance
- Using connection string `SERVERNAME` does not work
- Using connection string `SERVERNAME\` does work (note the backslash).

Thus, until yesterday the `SERVERNAME` connection was working fine.

And everybody's telling me that the `SERVERNAME\` connection is a abnormal one.

I've tried to connect with Windows authentication and SQL Server authentication, and cannot connect through `SERVERNAME` as my server name.

What should I do to recover previous functionality ?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: It isn't too bad.  Perhaps you could post the error that you receive and the version of SQL Server you are using (2005/2012)?

Comment: Can you connect to SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS now ? Is server SERVERNAME ping-ed ?

Comment: 1/ Sorry, Miss to tell about release :
- SQLEXPRESS  : 10.0.5500
- MSSQLSERVER : 10.50.4000

2/ SQLEXPRESS connect well :-). SERVERNAME is my Windows 7 development computer (localhost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use SERVER_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME. In you above described scenario when you use `.` which means localhost it connect you the the sql server default instance name. but is it really safe to let sql server decide which instance to connect to? obviously not.

Let your connection string decide which server and what instance to connect to by using full path i.e `ServerName\InstanceName`. and do not worry much about other issue. as they say `Keep it simple` :)

Comment: I do not know the INSTANCE_NAME of the MSSQLSERVER...
Thus, cannot connecte with SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME...
What should I found it ?

Comment: Too bad... Already have tried this, but this gave me then "SERVERNAME" without the backslash !

Comment: MSSQLSERVER is the instance name. to futher confirm it you can use `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` read here to learn more about [`@@SERVERNAME`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx) this will return the ServerName if you have the defualt instance name or if you have a non-default instance name it will return ServerName\InstanceName.

Comment: If it only returns the server name it means you are connected to the default instance name. which is MSSQLSERVER. Now if you connect to any other instance other then default and execute the same select there it will return the server_name\Instance_name

Comment: It means both are connected to the default instance. If you read the documentation you will understand it better I have provided you a link in my commmets.